# ubuntu installation does not detect my disk partition by created by windows 8

Tags: installation

I have bought a new Asus k55vj laptop and I have installed Windows 8. Now i want to install ubuntu 12.10 but ubuntu installation does not detect my disk partition. It only shows all hard disk and want me to delete all hard disk. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to shrink existing partition to create new partition(for ubuntu installation).

You can use GParted tool in ubuntu live cd/usb or you can do it using windows partition manager.Remember do not format the new partition(it will be taken care of by ubuntu installation).

Then use the ubuntu live usb/cd to install ubuntu.